# Can Monk with Warshaper increase the size category of unarmed strikes?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monk, unarmed-combat

From what I've researched, unarmed strikes are natural weapons even if natural weapons aren't unarmed strikes. Can a monk use Morphic Weapons to increase the size category of unarmed strikes? Emphasis mine:

> **Morphic Weapons (Su)**: As a move action, a warshaper can grow natural weapons such as claws or fangs, allowing a natural attack that deals the appropriate amount of damage according to the size of the new form (see Table 5—1 on page 296 of the Monster Manual). These morphic weapons need not be natural weapons that the creature already possesses. For example, a warshaper polymorphed into an ettin (Large giant) could grow a claw that deals 1d6 points of damage, or horns for a gore attack that deals 1d8 points of damage.
>
> **If the warshaper's form already has a natural weapon of that type, the
>   weapon deals damage as if it were one category larger.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Yes.

While unarmed strikes represent a very weird gray area/blending of manufactured and natural weapons, for the most part they are affected by external effects as if they were natural (and it is a class feature of the monk that they may have effects that usually only work on manufactured weapons work on their unarmed strikes).

For example, *magic fang* works on unarmed strikes (and *magic weapon* doesn’t, again unless you are a monk). Another example, the Improved Natural Attack feat can be taken for the unarmed strike (and at least one magic item, the *fanged ring*, gives Improved Natural Attack: Unarmed Strike while wearing it).

Warshaper’s Morphic Weapons is a similar effect, and should work consistently with other effects. Your unarmed strike should deal damage as if one size category larger than they would without it.